# Codeigniter - Avoid repeated code

Tags: codeigniter

I have a database table with some information about the website such as the site title, phone numbers etc... This information is needed on every page. Is there a way i could get those database values into variables on every page without having to write the same code in every page controllers?

Thanks,
Marais

Comment: put the logic `getData()` into the model that handles the database table; then call the method from any controller you need; If you're making the same call from different controllers during a single  request just use caching to avoid querying the database again for the same data

Comment: But this will still require me to have repeated code in each controller...

Comment: yes but that will be just two lines such as `$data = $this->some_model->get_data(); $view['data'] = $data;`

Comment: true, i guess that is smaller. Thanks that works!! :D

Comment: well you can't not repeat some code if you want the same data/functionality in different places; the point is to keep the duplication to minimum; there is definitely nothing wrong with calling the same function from different places

Comment: sure. See im new to programming im not sure what is and isnt wrong.

Answer (score 1):

How about using autoloading of codeigniter [AutoLoader](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)

Create your custom helper and the method to get the data you needed from your database, then just call the method on every view file that you need it to be shown.